# What is the best choice for data storage in Pandas for mixed type data?

Tags: python, pandas, storage

I am working on a large dataset that is stored as `ndjson` where each row of the data is a json object, I read this in line by line and use `pandas json_normalise()` to flatten each one and save it in a list as a dataframe, I then concat this list afterwards.

The whole process takes ~2 hours on a high powered machine so I would like to save the result so I dont have to repeat it, however, I have tried using to_hdfs and to_parquet but both have been failing and I believe it is due to the majority of columns having mixed data types where there could be strings, floats and ints which is an unavoidable consequence of a messy data collection system.

What would be the most appropriate way of storing this unprocessed data prior to cleaning it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here should help `pickle`.

For write `DataFrame/Series` use [`to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) .

For read back use [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html).